# How to use ng2-canvas-whiteboard in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

I want to use this npm-package in my Ionic 3 App:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-canvas-whiteboard

I did everything it says in this link.

Here is my package.json:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-canvas-whiteboard": "^1.1.1",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
```

This is the important part of my app.module.ts:

```html
import { CanvasWhiteboardModule } from 'ng2-canvas-whiteboard/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
   FormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   CanvasWhiteboardModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
```

this is my page.ts:

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import {CanvasWhiteboardUpdate} from 'ng2-canvas-whiteboard';



@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-deskriptorenanalyse',  
  templateUrl: 'deskriptorenanalyse.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None 
})
export class DeskriptorenanalysePage {

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)
   {

   }
   

  sendBatchUpdate(updates: CanvasWhiteboardUpdate[]) {
    console.log(updates);
  }
  onCanvasClear() {
    console.log("The canvas was cleared");
  }
  onCanvasUndo(updateUUID: string) {
    console.log(`UNDO with uuid: ${updateUUID}`);
  }
  onCanvasRedo(updateUUID: string) {
    console.log(`REDO with uuid: ${updateUUID}`);
  }
  
}
```

And this is the Page.html:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Entwicklung der Schlüsselfaktoren</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>


<div>
<canvas-whiteboard #canvasWhiteboard
                       [drawButtonClass]="'drawButtonClass'"
                       [drawButtonText]="'Draw'"
                       [clearButtonClass]="'clearButtonClass'"
                       [clearButtonText]="'Clear'"
                       [undoButtonText]="'Undo'"
                       [undoButtonEnabled]="true"
                       [redoButtonText]="'Redo'"
                       [redoButtonEnabled]="true"
                       [colorPickerEnabled]="true"
                       (onBatchUpdate)="sendBatchUpdate($event)"
                       (onClear)="onCanvasClear()"
                       (onUndo)="onCanvasUndo($event)"
                       (onRedo)="onCanvasRedo($event)">                    
</canvas-whiteboard>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

I thought that I have done everything needed to use this package, but these errors are  occurring:

[image]

Can you tell what I did wrong or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look and read your error message.

it sais the following isnt a known property:

```
drawButtonClass
```

That means that you forgot to assign or import the drawButtonClass.

You sholud probably assign that variable in the page.ts or import it from the package.

The same applies for all the other objects you used without declaring them.

Comment: To test whether the canvas whiteboard itself is working, I cut out all of the objects which caused the errors. Now I get the following Error: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'canvas-whiteboard' is not a known element:
1. If 'canvas-whiteboard' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'canvas-whiteboard' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`  What did I miss while installing this package?

Comment: @MarcelFieser you missed nothing installing the package. You have just not imported all the components

Comment: You are kind of right. @Stefan Peshikj solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

i created an Ionic project to see what the problem may be, and from the looks of it it seems that your ionic project may have been set up wrong.

First, your DeskriptorenanalysePage class (page.ts) has the decorator IonicPage(), which means that it also needs to have it's own NgModule so that it can work.

Also, your DeskriptorenanalysePage class needs to be added to the app.module file and added to the declarations and imports arrays so that Angular can see that it is your own component.

Also, since using @IonicPage() you need to register it as a child routing import so that Ionic deep linking can be made

I created a demo tabs project and added the canvas to the home tab and it seems to be working so i speculate that the Ionic Project Setup must be wrong, or maybe you did not see the errors shown when running ionic serve (if there were any).

Could you please confirm that the project setup is good

Edit: Please add the CanvasWhiteboardModule as an import in the DeskriptorenanalysePage's NgModule and it should do the trick

**Edit: There was a problem with the CanvasWhiteboardModule importing the BrowserModule which caused problems when LazyLoadedModules were being created (since BrowserModule should only be imported once in the AppModule).**

**This issue is fixed in version 1.1.2 of the ng2-canvas-whiteboard package.** Please update the package in package.json and the issue should be resolved

**Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for helping discover this bug.**

Comment: Since Ionic 3 every page.ts has it's own module.ts file. it looks like this: `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DeskriptorenanalysePage } from './deskriptorenanalyse';
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DeskriptorenanalysePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(DeskriptorenanalysePage),

  ],
  exports: [
    DeskriptorenanalysePage
  ]
})
export class DeskriptorenanalysePageModule {}`.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the imports of the whiteboardmodule in this file. I tried different versions, but none of them worked. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle the page.module.ts?

Comment: Do it the same way you would do in any NgModule, the same way as in the app.module.ts

Comment: Then it says: `Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need acces to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from alazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.` But when I import the CommonModule the error stays the same.

Comment: There was a problem with the module, see the latest EDIT above